# syntax error near unexpected token value in bash

Tags: bash, if-statement

I'm new to bash and I'm trying to write a script that will prompt the user to select a number, and open the corresponding file. Right now i just wanted to get the options to work properly but I get the error:

```
./filescript: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
./filescript: line 7: `elif [[$server == 2]]'
```

Anytime I try to make a selection when it's ran. Here's what I have, any advice is appreciated!

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Which file would you like to open: "
read input
if [[$input == 1]] then
    echo "This is the first option"
elif [[$input == 2]]
    echo "This is the second option"
else
    echo "Error"
fi
```

Comment: You should start using https://www.shellcheck.net - it would have pointed out everything that is wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're syntax error in your code.

- before then , `;` should added
- in the test brace , must have space around test condition
- you forgot `then` keyword in second `elif`

the correction will be

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Which file would you like to open: "
read input
if [[ $input == 1 ]] ;then
    echo "This is the first option"
elif [[ $input == 2 ]] ;then
    echo "This is the second option"
else
    echo "Error"
fi
```

See online version 
http://tpcg.io/8zfbh4

Answer (score 1):

I typically do my IF statements like this for strings

```
if [ "$input" == "1" ]
```

or like this for numerical

```
if [ $input -eq 1 ]
```

EDIT:  try putting a space after the `[` and before the `]`

```
$ if [[ $X == 1 ]] ; then echo "yes"; fi
yes

$ if [[$X == 1]] ; then echo "yes"; fi
bash: [[1: command not found
```